# React setState in a map function

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I cannot wrap my head around the issue below.

The issue relates to the asynchronous setState dimension. Usually I use the callback, but doesn't seem appropriate here.

My goal is to create a state (that I will be able to sort) which is obtained by iterating on different states which are themselves created in a map.

The function below calls my different methods, the ones we're interested in are the 2 last ones. `getUserPoints` and `sortArrayforUserRank`.

```
getPlayersByUser = () => {
database
  .ref(`pools/${this.state.selectedValue}`)
  .once("value")
  .then(data => {
    for (let item in data.val()) {
      this.setState({
        users: this.state.users.concat([item])
      });
      this.setState({ [item]: data.val()[item] });
    }
  })
  .then(this.makePlayersArray)
  .then(this.getUserPoints)
  .then(this.sortArrayforUserRank);


  getUserPoints = () => {
this.state.users.map(user => {
  // Create the dynamic name of the state, 1 for each user
  let userPoints = `${user}points`;

  // initializing the state for userPoint to be at 0 for future calculation
  this.setState({ [userPoints]: 0 });

  this.state[user].map(player => {
    database
      .ref(`players/${player}`)
      .child("points")
      .once("value")
      .then(data => {
        let points = parseInt(data.val());
        this.setState(state => ({
          [userPoints]: points + state[userPoints]
        }));
      });
  });
});
```

The `getUserPoints` allow me to dynamically create the state.userPoints summing all the points from the players for each user.

Then I was expecting the `sortArrayforUserRank` below to use the updated state.userPoints to create my final userArrayPoints state.

```
sortArrayforUserRank = () => {
this.state.users.map(user => {
  let userPoints = `${user}points`;
  this.setState(state => ({
    userArrayPoints: state.userArrayPoints.concat([
      { [user]: state[userPoints] }
    ])
  }));
});
```

Currently the userArrayPoints gets populated with 4 objects `{[user]:0}` instead of the final sum of points for each user. The issue there is that `sortArrayforUserRank` gets called before the previous setState are done

I would have loved to use the setState callback in `getUserPoints` but since I'm in the player map function it will get called for each player whereas I want to handle it at the user lvl to have the final sum of points.

I tried to use `componentDidUpdate`, and made sur to use functionnal setState as per those articles but couldn't figure it out.

https://medium.com/@shopsifter/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Your help will be glady appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Let me understand your `getUserPoints`, there are multiple users and each user has multiple players? Could you give a sample of how the users object might look like? And if I am correct you want to finally `setState` for your component state with users and their total points, for which you need not do so many state updates.

Comment: Hi @NanduKalidindi

You're right on my final goal - have the total points for each user based on their respective players

The individual user object in DB is looks like `{userName : "playerName1, playerName2, playerName3..."}`

I make it a individual state for each user which looks like `{userName: [playerName1, playerName2, playerName3 etc]}`

At the same time my users state object is an array `{users:[userName1, userName2 etc]}`

My current idea was to obtain a final state userArrayPoints which would look like `{[{userName1: totalUser1Points},{userName2: totalUser2Points}]}`

Answer (score 5):

You can't do what you are trying here with `setState` because it is asynchronous and will conflict with the different states available on each iteration in that `for ()` loop.

What you can do is extract the state first, manipulate it as needed, then run `setState` (at least in this one below)

```
.then(data => {
    // Pull out what you want to mess with here first
    const users = [ ...this.state.users ];
    const dataValObj = data.val();

    // Then use spread operator (or Object.assign/Array.concat)          
    this.setState({
      users: [ 
          ...users, 
          ...Object.keys(dataValObj)
      ],
      ...dataValObj
    });
})
```

And it seems you followed a similar pattern throughout the code.  Try and apply what I've done here to the other areas that are using loops with `setState` inside them.

Comment: Thanks @Deryck , but I have troubles figuring out how it can help me in that case, and I'm surely not fully grasping your answer.

I assume your logic would be used in `getUserPoints` after the `this.state.users` has been created.

In `getUsersPoints` I iterate over `user` as I use their name to access the value in the DB. 

I tried removing setState from the loop, but it always end up with the setState being called before I the promise (from the database request) is resolved. That's why I was using setState in a then following the request inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

found one way to do it using promise all below. It allows me to remove the setState from the loop and directly work on it instead of have to rely on 2 setstate. Both comments/answer helped me to process that,

```
  getUserPoints = () => {
this.state.users.map(user => {
  // Create the dynamic name of the state, 1 for each user
  let userPoints = `${user}points`;

  // initializing the state for userPoint to be at 0 for future calculation
  this.setState({ [userPoints]: 0 });

  let userCounter = 0;
  let promiseArrays = [];
  this.state[user].map(player => {
    let promise = database
      .ref(`players/${player}`)
      .child("points")
      .once("value")
      .then(data => {
        let points = parseInt(data.val());
        return (userCounter = userCounter + points);
      });
    promiseArrays.push(promise);
  });
  Promise.all(promiseArrays).then(() =>
    this.setState({
      userArrayPoints: this.state.userArrayPoints.concat({
        [user]: userCounter
      })
    })
  );
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Just use second argument in this.setState.

Second argument is a function that will be called after seting State.

this.setState({
          name:value
        },() => {this.nameOfTheFunctionYouWantToRunNext() });