# select RadioButton on the basis of dynamic value

Tags: react-native

I have three RadioButtons (Male, Female, Others) and I'm getting the data from the server.

What I want is when the `this.state.genderType == 'Male'` then the Male RadioButton should be selected automatically.

When `this.state.genderType == 'Female'` then Female RadioButton should be selected and so on.
Here is my state:

```
  SetStatefunction = () =>{
    const {retrievedata}  = this.state
      retrievedata.map((item)=>{
       this.setState({name: item.name})
        this.setState({dob: item.dob})
         this.setState({bloodgroup: item.bloodGroup})
          this.setState({email: item.email})
           this.setState({genderType: item.gender})
          this.setState({phone: item.mobile})
         this.setState({address: item.address})
        console.log(this.state.genderType)
      if(item.dob){
     let dob =  moment(item.dob).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    this.setState({dob: dob})
   }
  })
 }
```

Here is the code for my RadioButtons

```
<RadioGroup
  size={18}
  thickness={2}
  color="#58992c"
  style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}
  onSelect={(index, value) => {
    this.setState({ genderType: value });
  }}
>

  <RadioButton
    value={"Male"}
    style={{ alignItems: "center"}}
    name = "gender"
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Male</Text>
  </RadioButton>

  <RadioButton
    value={"Female"}
    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
    name = "gender"
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Female</Text>
  </RadioButton>

  <RadioButton
    value={"Other"}
    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
    name = "gender"
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Other</Text>
  </RadioButton>

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole code? We can't predict what data are you receiving from the server and how.

Comment: data is receiving properly. not issue in data code.

Comment: data is in props or state?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `checked` property to `RadioButton`,

```
<RadioGroup
  size={18}
  thickness={2}
  color="#58992c"
  style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}
  onSelect={(index, value) => {
    this.setState({ genderType: value });
  }}
>

  <RadioButton
    value={"Male"}
    style={{ alignItems: "center"}}
    name = "gender"
    checked = {data.gender === "Male"}
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Male</Text>
  </RadioButton>

  <RadioButton
    value={"Female"}
    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
    name = "gender"
    checked = {data.gender === "Female"}
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Female</Text>
  </RadioButton>

  <RadioButton
    value={"Other"}
    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
    name = "gender"
    checked = {data.gender !== "Male" && data.gender !== "Female"}
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Other</Text>
  </RadioButton>

</RadioGroup>
```

---

**Update**

There is issue with this function,

```
SetStatefunction = () => {
    const { retrievedata } = this.state
    retrievedata.map((item) => {
        this.setState({ name: item.name })
        this.setState({ dob: item.dob })
        this.setState({ bloodgroup: item.bloodGroup })
        this.setState({ email: item.email })
        this.setState({ genderType: item.gender })
        this.setState({ phone: item.mobile })
        this.setState({ address: item.address })
        console.log(this.state.genderType)
        if (item.dob) {
            let dob = moment(item.dob).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            this.setState({ dob: dob })
        }
    })
}
```

**If you have data in `retrievedata`, then why are you again iterating it?**

You are iterating `retrievedata`, and for every iteration you are calling multiple `setState` which is completely wrong.

`setState` is `async`. You should not call `setState` in `map`, it will only create conflict and you never get desired output.

You can directly use `retrievedata` array to get values,

```
checked = {retrievedata[0].gender.toLowerCase() === "male"}
```

Comment: thank you for the response. but not working. but not selected automatically on the basis of data

Comment: Can you show us where is your data exactly? Or post complete component, so that we can see from where data is coming.

Comment: i'm saving the data in the state. not problem is in data fetching. because other fields are properly changing dynamically

Comment: Then instead of `data.gender` use `this.state.data.gender` (considering data is an object)

Comment: ya i'm doing this same. this.state.genderType.....data.gender i gives as the example

Comment: You are doing wrong `SetStatefunction`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735600/react-setstate-in-a-map-function

Comment: i assigned directly to the state. using `this.setState({genderType: retreiveData[0].gender})` but problem is not solved.

Comment: If your data already in state variable called `retreiveData`, then why you again want to set in state? Can't you directly use this - `checked = {retrievedata[0].gender.toLowerCase() === "male"}`?