# setState() With Object.keys() Through Fetch Requests In Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the state with data received from a fetch request in the parent component. I am receiving an array of objects that each have the following keys: ‘name’, ‘artist’, ‘url’, ‘cover’, ‘lrc’, and ‘theme’. I am using Object.keys() to map over the object data, but I am wondering how I can set the state in this way so as to have multiple objects with those six keys be stored in the state so my state will look like:

this.state = { data: [{ {…}, {…}, {…}, etc… }] }

One big issue is that my data - from a fetch request in the parent - is not rendering in this tempComp component. I am passing the data in as a prop (this.props.playlist). Why is the fetched data in the parent not rendering in the tempComp component, and how can I set state with multiple objects, as I attempted below with Object.keys()? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class tempComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      audio: [{
        name: '',
        artist: '',
        url: '',
        cover: '',
        lrc: '',
        theme: ''
      }]

    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('playlist in componentDidMount()', this.props.playlist) //<--- AudioPlayer data should be coming in here

    var json = this.props.playlist;
    var arr = [];
    Object.keys(json).forEach(function (key) {
      arr.push(json[key]);
    });
    arr.map(item => {
      this.setState({
        audio: [{
          name: item.name,
          artist: item.artist,
          url: item.url,
          cover: item.cover,
          lrc: item.lrc,
          theme: item.theme
        }]
      })
    })
    console.log(this.state.audio);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default tempComp
```

And here is the parent component, for clarification:

```
export default class PostContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: '',
      episodeData: [],
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/episode/${id}/playlist`);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      episodeData: jsonData, //this is working!...
      id: id
    });
    console.log(this.state.episodeData) //...see?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>

      <TempComp playlist={this.state.episodeData} />

        <AudioPlayer playlist={this.state.episodeData} />
        <Link id='home-link' to='/' activeClassName='active'>Homepage</Link>
        {this.state.episodeData.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="word-content">
            <h2 className="show-title">{item.post_title}</h2>
            <div className="episode-post-content">{item.post_content}</div>
            </div>
            ))}
            <Table data={this.state.data} />
            <div className="bottom-link">
              <Link id='home-link' to='/' activeClassName='active'>Homepage</Link>
            </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You're getting a bit tricked here. You can't setState in a map because it's an asynchronous method. You can do a few tricks but check this out first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735600/react-setstate-in-a-map-function

Comment: Why are you even using map function, can't you just:-
      this.setState({
        audio: arr
    });

Is there any issue using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been a bit tricked here with the way setState works. It's an [asynchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735600/react-setstate-in-a-map-function) which means it's not going to run in tandem with your map. You could use a setTimeout or an await which I can see is possible given your `componentDidMount` is prefixed by `async`. However, if I can take the liberty, i'd recommend you make some small changes like so:

---

```
const json = {
    apple: { yum: false },
    peach: { yum: true }
};

const yummyness = Object.keys(json).map(key => {
    return { yum: json[key].yum }
});

// yumminess will render:  [{ yum: false }, { yum: true }]
this.setState({ yummyness });
```

---

**What I've done here is a few things:**

1. If data isn't changing, assign it to a const, you can learn more about that [here](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e)
2. Map returns an array. This can be really handy such as now, so instead of pushing to your `arr` value, I've just returned an object to prevent you doing your second map.
3. Finally, as I mentioned earlier setState is asynchronous and a bit of a slippery sucker! So to avoid that I'm just letting the map do it's thing and THEN I've assigned it to yummyness.
4. **Bonus Round**: I've used fruit but I've left most of your naming the same. `json` is your `props.playlist` and yumminess is your `arr`

Hope this helped!

Comment: And - if you're still interested in looking at this :-) ... do you have any ideas as to why the fetched data in the parent component isn't passing through as props to the child (TempComp) component? When I console log 'this.props.playlist' in the componentDidMount() method, it returns an empty array...

Comment: Can you please: console.log this.state.episodeData in your render above the return, and also, parse through a dummy array and see if that comes into tempComp as Props? 

Thanks!